# Remove characters from beginning and end string

Tags: php, preg-replace, substr, strpos

I want to ouput only `MYID` from URL.  What I did so far:

```
$url = "https://whatever.expamle.com/display/MYID?out=1234567890?Browser=0?OS=1";
echo substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "?out="));
```

output: https://whatever.expamle.com/display/MYID

```
$url = preg_replace('#^https?://whatever.expamle.com/display/#', '', $url);
echo $url;
```

ouput: MYID?out=1234567890?Browser=0?OS=1

How can I combine this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the original URL without any formatting.  Seeing `----` or multiple `?` in the query string is highly unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the string is always a Uniform Resource Locator (URL), like you present it in your question,

given the following string:

```
$url = "https://whatever.expamle.com/display/MYID?out=1234567890?Browser=0?OS=1";
```

you can benefit from parsing it first:

```php
$parts = parse_url($url);
```

and then making use of the fact that MYID is the last path component:

```
$str = preg_replace(
    '~^.*/(?=[^/]*$)~' /* everything but the last path component */,
    '',
    $parts['path']
);

echo $str, "\n"; # MYID
```

and then depending on your needs, you can combine with any of the other parts, for example just the last path component with the query string:

```php
echo "$str?$parts[query]", "\n"; # MYID?out=1234567890?Browser=0?OS=1
```

Point in case is: If the string already represents structured data, use a dedicated parser to divide it (cut it in smaller pieces). It is then easier to come to the results you're looking for.

If you're on Linux/Unix, it is even more easy and works without a regular expression as the `basename()` function returns the paths' last component then (does not work on Windows):

```php
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)), 
     '?',
     parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), 
     "\n"
     ;
```

- https://php.net/parse_url
- https://php.net/preg_replace
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution, we can use regex with `preg_match_all`:

```php
$url = "https://whatever.expamle.com/display/MYID?out=1234567890?Browser=0?OS=1";
preg_match_all("/\/([^\/]+?)\?/", $url, $matches);
print_r($matches[1][0]);  // MYID
```

Comment: This outputs only `MYID`, but i needed to output `---MYID---`

Comment: I deleted the --- from my original question, maybe this is better understandable then

Comment: I have reverted your question and given you a more specific regex solution.  Please do not make drastic changes to your question after others have answered.  The site doesn't work this way.